# inserting a button into html file or dynamically to send content of page to a server

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

I am trying to put a button inside a html code either into a file or dynamically as it loads. I am python system coder so I am trying to solve it by Python.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer


html="" #Holds the mainhtml loadaed
updated_html =""  #Holds the html with the new layout
updated_html_file= open('reviw.htmlx', 'w'); # file pointer to the html file with action buttons
with open('aaaa.html', 'r+') as myfile:
    html=myfile.read();
    update_html=update_html.replace("</a>","</a><input type=\"button\" value=DMCA onclick=\"window.location.href='.html';\">DMCA</button>

    updated_html_file.write(update_html);    #Puts the DMCA button next to it
updated_html_file.close();

import socket;
import sys;

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
server_address = ('localhost', 9999);
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address;
sock.bind(server_address);
# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection';
    connection, client_address = sock.accept();
    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address;

        # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it;
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(16);
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data;
        if data:
            print >>sys.stderr, 'sending data back to the client';
            connection.sendall(data);
        else:
            print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address;
        break
    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close();
```

Now we have the buttons there and I have a server here that simply listens to port 80 and spits out what it received. What I have literally no clue how to do is how do I send the anchor link or the text to server. I googled HTML and JS but this is the FIRST time I am touching web in html so neither understood anything nor found anything I could extrapolate from. I thought about perhaps sending as a post method to a http server? given the number of buttons I could not figure out how to achieve that either :(

Is there anyway I could achieve this being a true html novice? any tips are very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you heard of JQuery? In my opinion it makes the transition to javascript a little easier. Also Fiddler may help monitor what is happening. Are you looking for code to asynchronously send content from a page to the server?

Comment: You have to remember: Python is a server side script. It runs once and then serves the HTML. Once the HTML is served Python can't change it - only JavaScript can. I would recommend you do a JavaScript tutorial - you will **have** to learn it at some point to do anything useful with a website. As @Lola mentioned, once you know some JS, take a look at JQuery: it's a very nice simple/powerful JS library for doing lots of common things (such as network requests).